# Find the Longest String in Multiple Texts

Tags: algorithm

I have the following problem. There are two given text and I need to find the longest string that occurs in both. I think we should create a string array where we should put common strings and then compare their length and which length will be largest print. Is there a fast method to this?

Answer (score 5):

The longest common substring problem:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem

Comment: Wikipedia has pseudocode, try converting that to your language of choice. If you still have problems then open another question.